# Lists won't produce result due to it must be a string. 8 Ball Fortune

Tags: python

The problem with my code is that when running it to see if the first word of the question is in the query list. It won't give anything back due to being a int. Can anyone point me towards right direction ?

```
import random 

response = [ 'Yes, of course!',"Without a doubt,yes.",
             'For sure!','Ask me later.',
             'I am not sure.',
             'I will tell you after my nap.',
             'No Way!','I do not think so.',
             'The answer is clearly NO.']

query = ['Will','Are','Is','Am','Do','Can','May']

# Global lists ^^^

def main(response,query,ran):
    # The program that 
    print('Ask a question that can only be answered in yes or no.')
    question = input()
    if question(0) in query():
      ran(response,query)
      res = ran(response,query)
      print(res)
      again = input('Enter Y or y to play again. Enter N or n to exit.')
      if again in ['y','Y']:
          main(lists)
      else:
          print('This program will now close.')

def ran(response,query):
    res = random.choice(response)
    return res

main(response,query,ran)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies here `question.index(0) in lists`. You are comparing apples with pears. index will yield a number and you are comparing it with the actual definition of the `lists` function. You might want to rethink what you want to compare.

Secondly, you will have extra errors, you are using `random.sample` in a bad way, you should be doing `random.sample(response, 1)[0]`, I'm presuming you want to pick a random response from that collection.

Thirdly, what is the `lists()` function supposed to do?

Comment: The OP isn't using `in` on any lists here.... `lists` is a function... You can check an integer is in a list of strings if you want - but you just won't get a truthy result... however, you can't check if something is `in` a function...

Comment: gotcha! didn't see that comparison which is even worse than what I thought.

Comment: Yeah... that `question.index(0) in lists` is wrong in both the `.index(0)` and `in lists` part... Not quite sure what that `lists` function is meant to be doing... it doesn't even look necessary

Comment: Yeah @JonClements I'm trying to assign a number to one of the response answers. I took out the lists function and made them globals. Im just having trouble with out put now

Comment: @Janes could you edit your questions and make it very clear what is it that you want to achieve with the script so that we can help you better?